# Java Swing edit user popup

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a window to edit user info in a database but I can't seem to figure out a proper way to do the popup window. I want it to show the current info of the user, save the info to database on save button click and close the window when cancel is clicked - and I've done this using a new JFrame and JPanel but when I close that window and open another it shows the previous users info.

I'm not sure what parts of my code you'll need and I don't want to flood this question with a ton of code so this is the event that opens the window, let me know if theres something else I need to show.

```
        employee_list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            JTable employee_list =(JTable) me.getSource();
            Point p = me.getPoint();
            int row = employee_list.rowAtPoint(p);
            if (me.getClickCount() == 2) {
                final JFrame editEmployee = new JFrame();

                panel_5.setLayout(null);

                textField = new JTextField();
                textField.setText(userList[row][0].toString());
                textField.setColumns(10);
                textField.setBounds(6, 28, 40, 28);
                panel_5.add(textField);

                textField_1 = new JTextField();
                textField_1.setText(userList[row][1].toString());
                textField_1.setColumns(10);
                textField_1.setBounds(54, 28, 80, 28);
                panel_5.add(textField_1);

                textField_2 = new JTextField();
                textField_2.setText(userList[row][2].toString());
                textField_2.setColumns(10);
                textField_2.setBounds(146, 28, 122, 28);
                panel_5.add(textField_2);

                textField_3 = new JTextField();
                textField_3.setText(userList[row][3].toString());
                textField_3.setColumns(10);
                textField_3.setBounds(280, 28, 122, 28);
                panel_5.add(textField_3);

                textField_4 = new JTextField();
                textField_4.setText(userList[row][5].toString());
                textField_4.setColumns(10);
                textField_4.setBounds(436, 28, 122, 28);
                panel_5.add(textField_4);

                final JCheckBox checkBox_1 = new JCheckBox("");
                checkBox_1.setBounds(407, 33, 17, 18);

                panel_5.add(checkBox_1);

                JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("ID");
                label_1.setBounds(18, 6, 17, 16);
                panel_5.add(label_1);

                JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("Name");
                label_2.setBounds(73, 6, 40, 16);
                panel_5.add(label_2);

                JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("Email");
                label_3.setBounds(171, 6, 55, 16);
                panel_5.add(label_3);

                JLabel label_4 = new JLabel("Do not edit for now");
                label_4.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 10));
                label_4.setBounds(280, 3, 122, 22);
                panel_5.add(label_4);

                JLabel label_5 = new JLabel("Call?");
                label_5.setBounds(405, 6, 29, 16);
                panel_5.add(label_5);

                JLabel label_6 = new JLabel("Phone number");
                label_6.setBounds(446, 6, 94, 16);
                panel_5.add(label_6);

                JButton cancelNew = new JButton("Cancel");
                cancelNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        editEmployee.dispose();
                    }
                });
                cancelNew.setBounds(382, 62, 90, 28);
                panel_5.add(cancelNew);

                JButton saveNew = new JButton("Save..");
                saveNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        List<String> user_arrayNew = new ArrayList<String>();
                        if (!textField.getText().trim().equals("")){
                            user_arrayNew.add(ID.getText().trim());
                        }
                        if (!textField_1.getText().trim().equals("")){
                            user_arrayNew.add(email.getText().trim());
                        }
                        if (!textField_2.getText().trim().equals("")){
                            user_arrayNew.add( pass.getText().trim());
                        }
                        if (!textField_3.getText().trim().equals("")){
                            user_arrayNew.add(name.getText().trim());
                        }
                        if(checkBox_1.isSelected()){
                            user_arrayNew.add("yes");
                            if (!textField_4.getText().trim().equals("")){
                            user_arrayNew.add(phone.getText().trim());
                            }
                        }
                        if(!user_arrayNew.isEmpty()){
                        if(!checkBox_1.isSelected()){
                            user_arrayNew.add("no");
                            user_arrayNew.add("N/A");
                        }}
                        if(!user_arrayNew.isEmpty()){
                            String[] userNew = user_arrayNew.toArray(new String[6]);
                            String input = userNew[2];
                             String hashpassNew = null;
                            try {
                                hashpassNew = Lottery.hashpass.sha1(input);
                            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                             userNew[2] = hashpassNew;
                                Lottery.employees.editEmployeeMysql(userNew);
                            }
                    }
                });
                saveNew.setBounds(468, 62, 90, 28);
                panel_5.add(saveNew);

                System.out.println("test"+row);
                editEmployee.setSize(564, 100);
                editEmployee.getContentPane().add(panel_5);
                centerWithinScreen(editEmployee);
                editEmployee.setFocusable(true);
                editEmployee.setUndecorated(true);
                editEmployee.setVisible(true);
                }
        }
    });
```

This was the best solution for what I wanted-

I hadn't removed the panel contents after close so when opening a new window the fields weren't replaced.

calling removeAll() on the panel in my cancel button and calling validate() and repaint() on it when initializing it solved my issue. I should mention though that panel_5 is not initialized within this mouselistener.

Revised code (plus a few minor alterations here and there relating to my mysql methods):

```
employee_list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        JTable employee_list =(JTable) me.getSource();
        Point p = me.getPoint();
        final int row = employee_list.rowAtPoint(p);
        if (me.getClickCount() == 2) {
            final JFrame editEmployee = new JFrame();

            panel_5.setLayout(null);

            textField = new JTextField();
            textField.setText(userList[row][0].toString());
            textField.setColumns(10);
            textField.setBounds(6, 28, 40, 28);
            panel_5.add(textField);

            textField_1 = new JTextField();
            textField_1.setText(userList[row][1].toString());
            textField_1.setEditable(false);
            textField_1.setColumns(10);
            textField_1.setBounds(54, 28, 80, 28);
            panel_5.add(textField_1);

            textField_2 = new JTextField();
            textField_2.setText(userList[row][2].toString());
            textField_2.setColumns(10);
            textField_2.setBounds(146, 28, 122, 28);
            panel_5.add(textField_2);

            textField_3 = new JTextField();
            final String oldPass = userList[row][3].toString();
            textField_3.setColumns(10);
            textField_3.setBounds(280, 28, 122, 28);
            panel_5.add(textField_3);

            textField_4 = new JTextField();
            textField_4.setText(userList[row][5].toString());
            textField_4.setColumns(10);
            textField_4.setBounds(436, 28, 122, 28);
            panel_5.add(textField_4);

            final JCheckBox checkBox_1 = new JCheckBox("");
            checkBox_1.setBounds(407, 33, 17, 18);

            panel_5.add(checkBox_1);

            JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("ID");
            label_1.setBounds(18, 6, 17, 16);
            panel_5.add(label_1);

            JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("Name");
            label_2.setBounds(73, 6, 40, 16);
            panel_5.add(label_2);

            JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("Email");
            label_3.setBounds(171, 6, 55, 16);
            panel_5.add(label_3);

            JLabel label_4 = new JLabel("New Password");
            label_4.setBounds(280, 3, 122, 10);
            panel_5.add(label_4);

            JLabel optional = new JLabel("Blank = no change");
            optional.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 10));
            optional.setBounds(280, 3, 122, 30);
            panel_5.add(optional);

            JLabel label_5 = new JLabel("Call?");
            label_5.setBounds(405, 6, 29, 16);
            panel_5.add(label_5);

            JLabel label_6 = new JLabel("Phone number");
            label_6.setBounds(446, 6, 94, 16);
            panel_5.add(label_6);

            JButton cancelNew = new JButton("Cancel");
            cancelNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    panel_5.removeAll();
                    editEmployee.dispose();
                }
            });
            cancelNew.setBounds(382, 62, 90, 28);
            panel_5.add(cancelNew);

            JButton saveNew = new JButton("Save..");
            saveNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    List<String> user_arrayNew = new ArrayList<String>();
                    if (!textField.getText().trim().equals("")){
                        user_arrayNew.add(textField.getText().trim());
                    }
                    if (!textField_1.getText().trim().equals("")){
                        user_arrayNew.add(textField_1.getText().trim());
                    }
                    if (!textField_2.getText().trim().equals("")){
                        user_arrayNew.add(textField_2.getText().trim());
                    }
                    if (!textField_3.getText().trim().equals("")){
                        user_arrayNew.add(textField_3.getText().trim());
                    }else{
                        user_arrayNew.add(oldPass);
                    }
                    if(checkBox_1.isSelected()){
                        user_arrayNew.add("yes");
                        if (!textField_4.getText().trim().equals("")){
                        user_arrayNew.add(textField_4.getText().trim());
                        }
                    }else{
                        user_arrayNew.add("no");
                        user_arrayNew.add("N/A");
                    }
                    if(!user_arrayNew.isEmpty()){
                        String[] userNew = user_arrayNew.toArray(new String[6]);
                        if (!textField_3.getText().trim().equals("")){
                        String input = userNew[3];
                         String hashpassNew = null;
                        try {
                            hashpassNew = Lottery.hashpass.sha1(input);
                        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                         userNew[3] = hashpassNew;
                        }else{
                            userNew[3] = oldPass;
                        }
                            Lottery.employees.editEmployeeMysql(userNew);
                            panel_5.removeAll();
                            editEmployee.dispose();
                        }
                }
            });
            saveNew.setBounds(468, 62, 90, 28);
            panel_5.add(saveNew);

            panel_5.validate();
            panel_5.repaint();

            System.out.println("test"+row);
            editEmployee.setSize(564, 100);
            editEmployee.getContentPane().add(panel_5);
            centerWithinScreen(editEmployee);
            editEmployee.setFocusable(true);
            editEmployee.setUndecorated(true);
            editEmployee.setVisible(true);
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't need to do the "solved" thing that you see on a lot of forums. On SO, it's better to post an answer if you solved it yourself and "accept" it. That way, others who have a similar problem can very easily and quickly see the solution, and it can be voted on separately. Alternatively you could also accept Hovercraft's answer if you think it contains very essential / indispensable information for this problem.

Comment: I can't answer it myself for 8 hours, Hovercraft's answer is useful but I'll post an answer relating specifically to the code I has written asap

Comment: If the problem is due to an error that could never have been guessed by the code or information originally placed in the question, then the solution is not likely to help future visitors to this site, and you might as well just delete this question. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Myself, I'd try to make this as easy as possible:

- First create a JPanel that takes in the new information.
- Next display the JPanel in a JOptionPane, not a JFrame. A JOptionPane is *modal* by default, meaning you will know exactly when the user is done using it, since program flow will resume from right after where you displayed it.
- Because it is modal, the dialog will prevent user interaction with the calling window until the dialog has been fully dealt with.
- Use a `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` which will return an int that will tell me how the user responds, whether they press OK, cancel or escape out.
- Once I know that the user pressed OK, then I would update my database with the new information extracted from my JPanel's components.

---

As an aside, you should avoid use of null layout as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain.

---

**Edit**
For example, please have a look at the GUI below. It contains two JPanels objects that hold the same components, one shown in a JFrame, with all components disabled, and one shown in a JOptionPane where you can edit the components, and thereby alter the contents displayed on the non-editable JFrame:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FooGui2 {
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      DataPanel dataPanel = new DataPanel();
      dataPanel.setEnabled(false);
      dataPanel.setId("10x");
      dataPanel.setName("Mickey Mouse");
      dataPanel.setEmail("MMouse@GMail.com");
      dataPanel.setCall(false);
      dataPanel.setPhone("555-111-1212");
      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new UpdateDataAction(dataPanel, "Update",
            KeyEvent.VK_U)));

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Parent GUI");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(dataPanel.getMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class UpdateDataAction extends AbstractAction {
   private DataPanel parentDataPanel;
   private DataPanel childDataPanel;

   public UpdateDataAction(DataPanel dataPanel, String name, int mnemonic) {
      super(name);
      putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      this.parentDataPanel = dataPanel;
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      if (childDataPanel == null) {
         childDataPanel = new DataPanel();
      }

      childDataPanel.setId(parentDataPanel.getId());
      childDataPanel.setName(parentDataPanel.getName());
      childDataPanel.setEmail(parentDataPanel.getEmail());
      childDataPanel.setCall(parentDataPanel.isCall());
      childDataPanel.setPhone(parentDataPanel.getPhone());

      int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
            parentDataPanel.getMainPanel(), childDataPanel.getMainPanel(),
            "Update Information JOptionPane", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

      if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
         // !! if opted to change the parent data, then do it!
         parentDataPanel.setId(childDataPanel.getId());
         parentDataPanel.setName(childDataPanel.getName());
         parentDataPanel.setEmail(childDataPanel.getEmail());
         parentDataPanel.setCall(childDataPanel.isCall());
         parentDataPanel.setPhone(childDataPanel.getPhone());
      }
   }
}

class DataPanel {
   private static final int I_GAP = 5;
   private static final Insets INSETS = new Insets(I_GAP, I_GAP, I_GAP, I_GAP);
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private JTextField idField = new JTextField(4);
   private JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);
   private JTextField emailField = new JTextField(15);
   private JCheckBox callCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
   private JTextField phoneField = new JTextField(15);
   private JComponent[] components = { idField, nameField, emailField,
         callCheckBox, phoneField };

   public DataPanel() {
      mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      addLabelComponent("ID", idField, 0, -1f);
      addLabelComponent("Name", nameField, 1, -1f);
      addLabelComponent("EMail", emailField, 2, -1f);
      addLabelComponent("Call", callCheckBox, 3, -1f);
      addLabelComponent("Phone", phoneField, 4, -1f);
   }

   private void addLabelComponent(String labelText, JComponent jComp,
         int xPosition, float labelPoints) {
      JLabel label = new JLabel(labelText, SwingConstants.CENTER);
      if (labelPoints > 0) {
         label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(labelPoints));
      }
      // label position
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = xPosition;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      gbc.insets = INSETS;
      mainPanel.add(label, gbc);

      // component position
      gbc.gridy = 1;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
      mainPanel.add(jComp, gbc);
   }

   public void setId(String id) {
      idField.setText(id);
   }

   public String getId() {
      return idField.getText();
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      nameField.setText(name);
   }

   public String getName() {
      return nameField.getText();
   }

   public void setEmail(String email) {
      emailField.setText(email);
   }

   public String getEmail() {
      return emailField.getText();
   }

   public void setCall(boolean call) {
      callCheckBox.setSelected(call);
   }

   public boolean isCall() {
      return callCheckBox.isSelected();
   }

   public void setPhone(String phone) {
      phoneField.setText(phone);
   }

   public String getPhone() {
      return phoneField.getText();
   }

   public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
      mainPanel.setEnabled(enabled);
      for (JComponent component : components) {
         component.setFocusable(false);
         component.setEnabled(false);
      }
   }

   public JComponent getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

}
```

Comment: I tried a JOption pane before this but it's not nearly as customizable as a new frame

Comment: @BrandenPatey: that's only because you're not fully familiar with the power of the "simple" JOptionPane. Trust me, this baby's as customizable as the JPanel that you put into it. Hang on one sec and I'll show you.

Answer (score 0):

This was the best solution for what I wanted, but look at HoverCraft Full Of Eels' answer as well-

I hadn't removed the panel contents after close so when opening a new window the fields weren't replaced.

calling removeAll() on the panel in my cancel button then calling validate() and repaint() on it when initializing it solved my issue.